# Get friend name using email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is a "send to a friend" form, which is used to send HTML emails to friends. The user is connected using Facebook Graph, I can ask for any permissions.

I want to get friend's name (if the friend is Facebook-friend) using Facebook API. I figure, if I have emails address, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very easy to do this, and you don't need the e-mail address.
once the user authorized your application, even with out asking for any other permissions, you should be able to access the users friends list, as you can see here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
(under the Connections sections, there's the friends collection http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends)

you can try to see the result here:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friends

as you can see, the name of the users is present and you can use it.
hope this helps.

Comment: You are missing the point. I have friend's email, I need to get his name.

Comment: facebook don't let applications get the e-mail addresses of users friends (you can see here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ that the email for Friends permission is N/A)
so if the only piece of info you have on the friend is his e-mail, then you can not get his name.

Comment: I do not ask for friend's email. I am asking Facebook to give me details (id, name) of a person with given `email` if he is user's friend.

Comment: as i said, the e-mail address of a user friends are not available for you.  when a user authorize your application he also grant you certain permissions.  check the link i included in my last comment and see the list of possible permissions, some of them (the 2nd column) regard the user friends.  facebook don't have a permission for the friends e-mail address, only for the e-mail of the logged in user that authorized the app. since facebook won't let you near the e-mail of friends, you can not get the details of a user based on his e-mail.

Comment: @Guy, Nitzan Tomer is correct.  You cannot and will not get any email information for an app user's friend via the API. It would be considered a huge invasion of privacy if you could.